# Placing a photo and a text adjacent to each other

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I am very new to react-Native. I am trying to create this Mobile app in android using react-Native. I have a top logo on my page. I am trying to make the logo cover the top border of the phone stretching from left border to right border and then right underneath the logo, I am trying to put a photo and a text adjacent to the photo. Somehow the top logo has small space above the logo which I cannot remove and there is huge space between the logo and the other image underneath it. I am unable to display the text. I also want to show some breaks in the text which are also not showing. I am getting below error:

[image]

Below is my code

```
     type Props = {};
     export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (

      <View style={styles.container}>
       <Image 
           resizeMode="contain" 
           style={styles.logo} 
           source={require('./Resources/logo.jpg')} />
      </View>

       <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Image
            resizeMode="contain"
            source={{uri: './Resources/photo.png'}}
            style={styles.photo} />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>Welcome to our <br>website!. Our website has <br> been designed to <br> provide you with easy <br> access to information <BR> and a variety of online <br> services to assist you <br> with your needs.</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
```

The style sheets are below:

```
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    position: 'relative'
  },
   logo: {
      position: 'absolute',
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      right: 0,
      width: 350

    },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },

  photo:
  {
    top:0,
    width:180,
    height: 300

  }

  container3: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      justifyContent: 'flex-end',
      borderBottomWidth: 1,

   },

});
```

any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The render function requires that you return only one DOM element. Therefore, you have to do something like (by the way I do not know if you forgot some parts of the code, but the brackets at the end of the render function are not there):

```
render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View>
        <Image 
          resizeMode="contain" 
          style={styles.logo} 
          source={require('./Resources/logo.jpg')} />
      </View>
      <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Image
            resizeMode="contain"
            source={{uri: './Resources/photo.png'}}
            style={styles.photo} />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>Welcome to our <br>website!. Our website has <br> been designed to <br> provide you with easy <br> access to information <BR> and a variety of online <br> services to assist you <br> with your needs.</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

I did not check the style, but the error comes from the wrong use of JSX.